# Send Two Models into One View .Net in VB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq-to-sql, viewmodel

Edit one more time:

So it looks like I have figured out the address part too, in the class I have:

```
Public ReadOnly Property addresses As IEnumerable(Of Address)
        Get
            Return _these_addresses
        End Get
    End Property
```

And in the template I have:

```
<% For Each item In Model.addresses%>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href='<%: Url.Action("Edit", "Address", New With { .pid=Model.ContactID, .id=item.AddressID }) %>'>
                    <img src='<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Edit.jpg") %>' alt="Edit"  />
                </a> 
                <a href='<%: Url.Action("Details", "Address", New With { .pid=Model.ContactID, .id=item.AddressID }) %>'>
                    <img src='<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Detail.jpg") %>' alt="Details"  />
                </a> 
                <a href='<%: Url.Action("Delete", "Address", New With { .pid=Model.ContactID, .id=item.AddressID }) %>'>
                    <img src='<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Delete.jpg") %>' alt="Delete"  />
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.Street%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.City%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.StateID%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.CountryID%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.Zip%>
            </td>
         </tr>
    <% Next%>

    </table>
```

Edit Again:

I added this for every field in contact to the class and it is working...I just need to figure out the list of addresses now...

```
Public ReadOnly Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return _this_contact.FirstName
        End Get
    End Property
```

E D I T:

I about have it figured out:

I took a shot in the dark and made a ContactViewModel based of C examples I have found in research on how to do this

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports TotallyAwesomeCRM.Contact
Imports TotallyAwesomeCRM.Address

Public Class ContactViewModel
    Public contact As Contact
    Public address As Address
    Private _this_contact As Contact
    Private _these_addresses As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Address)

    Sub New(ByVal this_contact As Contact, ByVal these_addresses As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Address))
        ' TODO: Complete member initialization -this was added by the framework for me when I tried to call this class - I don't know what to do here - resources? 
        _this_contact = this_contact
        _these_addresses = these_addresses
    End Sub

End Class
```

So in my controller I:

```
Function Details(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim this_contact = GetContact(id)
        Dim these_addresses =
            From address In addressDataContext.Addresses, xref In addressDataContext.ContactAddressesXrefs
            Where address.AddressID = xref.AddressID And xref.ContactID = id
            Select address

        Dim viewModel = New ContactViewModel(this_contact, these_addresses)
        Return View(viewModel)
    End Function
```

And in the template it found the contact when I started typing Model.contact

<%: Model.contact.FirstName%>

But it gave me an error there: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It shouldn't be null...Please help me figure out the TODO

=================================================================================
O R I G I N A L  P O S T:

This is my first .NET venture ever. Everything I have done thus far I have figured out.

OK I have contacts, and contacts can have many addresses. I would like to display those addresses when I am viewing the detail of a Contact I would also like to have a container that is a list view of it's addresses. From that list view I want to be able to edit/delete/view the address.

My database structure is:

Tables:

```
Contacts
<contains contact info and PK>

Addresses
<contains address info and PK>

ContactAddressesXref
ContactID
AddressID
```

I have basically been editing the skeleton files the ASP.NET MVC empty application provides me

So here is the last thing I have tried in my Contact controller:

```
'
    ' GET: /Contacts/Details/5

    Function Details(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim this_contact =
                        From contact In dataContext.Contacts, address In addressDataContext.Addresses, xref In addressDataContext.ContactAddressesXrefs
                        Where address.AddressID = xref.AddressID And xref.ContactID = id
                        Select contact, address
        Return (View(this_contact))
    End Function
```

What I really wanted to do was query the addresses separately and send them in as their own set. I don't know if doing this is the right thing to do, but when I tried to send in 
two models it freaked out.

Which fails of course because the view has this in it:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of IEnumerable (Of TotallyAwesomeCRM.Contact))" %>
```

I tried:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of IEnumerable (Of TotallyAwesomeCRM.Contact, Of TotallyAwesomeCRM.Address))
```

It said:

```
 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP.views_contacts_details_aspx'.
```

So OK I tried:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"
```

And it throws and error here:

```
<div class="display-field"><%: Model.FirstName%></div>
```

Of  course, so Am I wrong in the controller? I know I can't have just System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of IEnumerable (Of TotallyAwesomeCRM.Contact)) that it will have to accept  more than that. I tried jacking with the Model.FirstName part saying Contact.FirstName, but that didn't come up in the drop down when I started writing Contact. I could do this easily in other languages, .Net seems to be a different ball game. Please help!

Comment: Please keep tags like "VB Visual Basic 2010 LINQ to SQL" out of the title. Just leave them in the tags.

Comment: OK I meant Visual Studio, I wasn't trying to make is search-able, I thought that those things were important to know to be able to answer the question, again though, I am brand new to .net, so maybe not.

Comment: Leave them in the tags and they're very searchable. But it makes the title readable.

Comment: PLEASE read [Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need "todo: complete member initialization..." (besides remove it :-)). You need to change the property for contact and address.

Try this:

```
Public Class ContactViewModel

    Private _this_contact As Contact
    Private _these_addresses As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Address)

    Sub New(ByVal this_contact As Contact, ByVal these_addresses As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Address))
        ' TODO: Complete member initialization -this was added by the framework for me when I tried to call this class - I don't know what to do here - resources? 
        _this_contact = this_contact
        _these_addresses = these_addresses
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Contact As Contact
        Get
            Return _this_contact
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Addresses As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Address)
        Get
            Return _these_addresses
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: So I don't need to create a property for every contact field? I have the addresses working that way, but I created a property for each field in contact, it works, but it is a lot of extra coding if I don't have to.

Comment: Correct. You just need a property in your viewmodel for Contact and Addresses. Then in your view you address the required property throw that. eg model.Contact.FirstName, model.Addresses(0).Country.